# Change format of data with RODBC package and export in SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server

I am using RODBC package in R to export data frames from R into SQL Server. So I have problem with exporting data because I want to set up format of data (e.g varchar,char, int, bigint etc.) and set destination for exporting (e.g export table in schema [integration].[test_data]).

I will try to explain this problem with simple data set airquality.

```
  # Airquality dataset
    test_data<-airquality
    
   #Export to SQLSERVER
    sqlSave(uat_conn, test_data, tablename =
                      "test_data",rownames=FALSE)

      # Structure of data
str(test_data)
'data.frame':   153 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Ozone  : int  41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
 $ Solar.R: int  190 118 149 313 NA NA 299 99 19 194 ...
 $ Wind   : num  7.4 8 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9 8.6 13.8 20.1 8.6 ...
 $ Temp   : int  67 72 74 62 56 66 65 59 61 69 ...
 $ Month  : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Day    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Below you can see how is look like dataset after importing into SQL-Server.

[image]

So here my question is how I can change data format in R with sqlSave command and after that export directly into SQL-Server in specific schema like [integration].[test_data] instead dbo.test_data ?

Comment: It's been nearly a decade since I used RODBC, but have you tried setting `tablename = "[integration].[test_data]"`?

Comment: The `?sqlSave` documentation say *"If `tablename` contains `.` and neither catalog nor schema is supplied, an attempt is made to interpret `qualifier.table` names as table `table` in schema `qualifier`"*, which sounds like `tablename = "integration.test_data"` should work.

Comment: As for the the column types, `sqlSave` has arguments `varTypes` and `typeInfo`, so you should be able to specify, e.g. `varTypes = c("Ozone" = "tinyint")`. Or something like that... as I said , it's been a while.

Comment: Aside... [`float`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql) is an approximate data type. If the precision of your wind data is important to you consider [`decimal` or `numeric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql) instead.